# Can not import module from Micro front end (mfe) anguler

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I created two projects
host application and remote application and configured modular federation for it
remote application run correctly but when try to serve host application display compile error
routing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2EKY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OLzI.png)
although I added file decl and declare in it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qOa7.png)
what is the problem please?